# How do I embed nancy in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, nancy

I need to host an embedded HTTP server within a WPF application and I was thinking of using [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/). However I'm having trouble getting started. My requirements are quite modest all I want to do is serve up some HTML and JavaScript and display it in a WebBrowser control.

How would I configure Nancy to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the self host the same way as the sample app ( https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Self ) - you may need to spin it up in a different thread though in WPF.